# React Native POST data to API is not working

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-native

I get `Notice: Undefined index` response when i post data to php API using FormData in React Native. But when i hard code parameters in the php file i am able to get results.

I have tried using `JSON.stringify` from React docs. I get same problem.
On the server side i tried suggested `file_get_contents('php://input')` which just returns null.

```
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append({
    latitude: '55555',
    longitude: '9999',
  });

fetch('http://localhost/someapi', {
    method:'POST',
    headers:{
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Content-length': data.length
    },
    body: data
    })
    .then((response)=>response.text())
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log('  Show response');
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.warn(err);
    });
```

I am using `response.text()` so i can display the error. otherwise `response.json()` gives me `Unexpected token <` because it returns html

Here is my PHP server code

```
 $lat =  $_POST['latitude'];
 $lng =  $_POST['longitude'];
 echo json_encode($lat);
```

I also tried

```
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $obj = json_decode($json, TRUE);
 echo $obj;
```

Comment: If you're going to post JSON, then say you are posting JSON: `'Content-Type': 'application/json',`

Comment: `'Content-length': data.length` – and work out the length of the JSON string, not the length of the data object (`undefined`).

Comment: console.log(response) check the details. or you can try with axios instead of fetch, so that error handling pretty easy.

Comment: @Quentin - I also tried `Content-Type': 'application/json` when using `body : JSON.stringify`. It hasn't solved my issue.

Comment: @MaheshK . I do have `console.log()` on the code already for debugging. Can you share more info about 'axios'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are passing `'multipart/form-data'` header , so you have to pass `formdata` to body instead of `JSON.stringify`

```
 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('latitude', 55555);
 formData.append('longitude', 9999);

fetch('http://localhost/someapi', {
    method:'POST',
    headers:{
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: formData
    })
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log('Response ==>',response);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.warn(err);
    });
```

Comment: thanks for picking that up. It actually doesnt work with `formData`. I modified the code multiple times so i made errors.

Comment: It seems like the php is not able to receive the formData..either using $_POST or $_GET.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the header object in your `Fetch`  API it would work fine

```
 headers:{
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
```

the solution should be like this

```
fetch('http://localhost/someapi', {
    method:'POST',
    body: data
    })
    .then((response)=>response.text())
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log('  Show response');
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.warn(err);
    });
```